# I am trying to translate the numpy.ndarray to tensor input feed to my model

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Model Input feed:
<tf.Tensor 'serialized_test:0' shape=(?, ?, ?, ?) dtype=float32>

Image numpy array:

```
{'test': array([[[[ 31,  24,  14],
         [ 24,  20,  11],
         [ 21,  21,  19],
         ...,
         [ 12,  23,  29],
         [ 14,  25,  31],
         [ 17,  28,  34]],

        [[ 12,  23,  27],
         [ 10,  21,  23],
         [ 20,  32,  32],
         ...,
         [ 23,  45,  56],
         [ 16,  40,  50],
         [  2,  31,  39]],

        [[  6,  33,  42],
         [  0,  21,  29],
         [  5,  25,  34],
         ...,
         [ 28,  47,  64],
         [ 13,  30,  48],
         [  0,  15,  34]],

        ...,

        [[ 29,  46,  56],
         [ 50,  68,  78],
         [ 29,  46,  56],
         ...,
         [ 84, 104, 111],
         [ 91, 111, 118],
         [ 69,  89,  96]],

        [[ 90, 110, 119],
         [ 96, 116, 125],
         [ 95, 115, 124],
         ...,
         [ 70,  85,  92],
         [ 81,  98, 106],
         [ 86, 103, 111]],

        [[100, 118, 128],
         [ 71,  89,  99],
         [ 62,  80,  90],
         ...,
         [  7,  44,  71],
         [ 14,  51,  77],
         [  7,  43,  65]]],


       [[[  6,  37,  57],
         [ 23,  49,  64],
         [ 20,  42,  53],
         ...,
         [ 41,  40,  36],
         [ 17,   8,   3],
         [ 24,   0,   0]],

        [[ 28,  29,  24],
         [ 19,  21,  18],
         [ 20,  22,  21],
         ...,
         [ 33,  75,  91],
         [ 34,  86, 110],
         [ 21,  84, 119]],

        [[ 12,  81, 120],
         [  5,  77, 117],
         [ 16,  85, 124],
         ...,
         [ 74,  96, 117],
         [ 74,  99, 119],
         [ 51,  78,  97]],

        ...,

        [[ 14,  22,  33],
         [ 27,  36,  45],
         [ 11,  20,  29],
         ...,
         [ 56,  63,  69],
         [ 74,  81,  87],
         [ 50,  59,  64]],

        [[ 40,  51,  55],
         [ 52,  63,  67],
         [ 26,  40,  41],
         ...,
         [ 13,  33,  44],
         [  7,  25,  37],
         [ 34,  50,  63]],

        [[ 10,  26,  39],
         [ 10,  28,  38],
         [ 39,  59,  68],
         ...,
         [ 87, 110, 126],
         [ 64,  87, 103],
         [ 63,  86, 102]]]], dtype=uint8)}
```

Required Output:

```
{'test': array([[[[0.12156863, 0.09411765, 0.05490196],
         [0.11372549, 0.09019608, 0.05098039],
         [0.09803922, 0.08235294, 0.04313725],
         ...,
         [0.1372549 , 0.03137255, 0.01960784],
         [0.18823529, 0.03529412, 0.03921569],
         [0.21568627, 0.03921569, 0.05098039]],

        [[0.12156863, 0.09803922, 0.05882353],
         [0.10980392, 0.09019608, 0.05490196],
         [0.09411765, 0.08235294, 0.04705882],
         ...,
         [0.13333333, 0.03529412, 0.02352941],
         [0.18823529, 0.04313725, 0.04705882],
         [0.21960784, 0.05098039, 0.05882353]],

        [[0.11764706, 0.10196078, 0.06666667],
         [0.10588235, 0.09411765, 0.05882353],
         [0.09019608, 0.07843137, 0.05098039],
         ...,
         [0.1254902 , 0.03921569, 0.02745098],
         [0.18823529, 0.05490196, 0.05490196],
         [0.22352941, 0.06666667, 0.07058824]],

        ...,

        [[0.06666667, 0.07058824, 0.05098039],
         [0.06666667, 0.07058824, 0.05490196],
         [0.06666667, 0.06666667, 0.05882353],
         ...,
         [0.10196078, 0.03921569, 0.02745098],
         [0.14117647, 0.04705882, 0.04705882],
         [0.16470588, 0.05098039, 0.05882353]],

        [[0.04313725, 0.04705882, 0.02745098],
         [0.04313725, 0.04705882, 0.02745098],
         [0.04313725, 0.04705882, 0.03137255],
         ...,
         [0.10588235, 0.03921569, 0.03137255],
         [0.14509804, 0.04705882, 0.04705882],
         [0.16862745, 0.05098039, 0.05882353]],

        [[0.02745098, 0.03137255, 0.01176471],
         [0.02745098, 0.03137255, 0.01176471],
         [0.02745098, 0.03137255, 0.01176471],
         ...,
         [0.10588235, 0.03921569, 0.03137255],
         [0.14509804, 0.04705882, 0.04705882],
         [0.16862745, 0.05098039, 0.05882353]]]])}
```

I don't know how to do this, Actually, I am trying to find text objects present in the image. There are some preprocessing techniques to achieve this out.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Edit:

The image is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf5RE.jpg)

My inference code

```
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

a = predictor.from_saved_model('my_model')  # this is a tensorflow saved model not a frozenmodel
image_np = np.array(Image.open("car_1.jpg"))
image_resized = np.resize(image_np, (2,70,130,3))
a({'test':image_resized})
```

Comment: can you provide, shape of required data

Comment: I don't quite get it. Is there some sort of text in the `{'test': array([[[[ 31,  24,  14],
         [ 24,  20,  11].....` part?

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat It's an image array

Comment: @Nagakiran  required data shape ---> (2, 70, 130, 3)

Comment: that means you want 2 images of height: 70, weight: 130, and 3 channels. Also, what is the current shape of your inputs?

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat I am trying to convert a single image to the required shape

Answer (score 1):

An image has 3 components -> height, width, and channels. In your case, the desired height is 70 and the width is 130. Now as for channels you can't control them. Then remain as it is. In your case that is 3.

Coming to the first value in `[2,70,130,3]` the `2` represents the `batch_size` or to say the number of images. In your case, as you have only `1` image you can't get `2` here. If you had `2` images then you would have gotten that.

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
import numpy as np
import cv2

# reading your image
img = Image.open(requests.get('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf5RE.jpg', stream=True).raw)

# You need to do this
new_img = cv2.resize(np.array(img), (70,130))
new_img = new_img / 255
```

The `new_img` is the desired output.

UPDATE:

Let's say you have a list of images. Then you can do it like this

```
def reshape_images(images):
    new_images = []
    for image in images:
        new_img = cv2.resize(np.array(img), (70,130))
        new_images.append(new_img)
    new_images = np.stack(new_images, axis=0)
    return new_images

new_images = reshape_images([img, img])
```

Comment: Almost there, If I have two images also how could I contact them to get the shape, which function I need to call?

Comment: your answer is right, I posted a wrong question, thanks for your time